# Unzip a large zip file and filter before storing in memory?

Tags: python

I am working with a very large zip file, and I am wondering whether it would be possible to filter contents of the zip file after decompression, without it being decompressed in memory, then storing the filtered content in memory and removing the decompressed file?

for example, filtering by a column value `year > 2010`, and selecting only specific columns `[col1:col3]`

I am trying to build a function for this however I am rather new to Python, so I require some assistance on how to incorporate this.

```
def unzip_file(file_path):

    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r')

    with ZipFile(file_path, "r") as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall("/tmp/extracts")

    with ZipFile('species.zip') as myzip:
        with myzip.open('species.tsv') as myfile:
            print(myfile.read())
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear unfortunetely. If I understand correctly, you want to unzip a file csv/tsv, but only save the lines that have certain characteristics to disk.

You started on the right path, you just need to implement the filtering and writing:

```
with open('outfile.tsv') as out_file, ZipFile('species.zip') as myzip,  myzip.open('species.tsv') as myfile:
    while True:
        line = myfile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        fields = line.split("\t")
        if fields: # Your criteria here
            out_file.writeline(line)
```

This essentially reads the file line by line, and only writes those lines to `outfile.tsv` that match the criteria